# How do I plot points and the model's line with glm gamma link=log?

Tags: r, graph, glm, gamma-distribution

I used glm with Gamma distribution and link=log to create my regressions. I am trying to create the model's line with visreg, but it creates just for the response and it doesn't show the points. I want to create a graph with all my points and the model's line. Is it possible using visreg? If it isn't, Is there another package that I could use to do that?

I have already tried to create the model's line using 'abline' and it didn't work.

```
MODEL=glm(y~x, family=Gamma(link='log'), data)
visreg(MODEL, scale='response')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of the `visreg` package implementation, but creating a line from scratch is not that difficult. Sadly `abline` wont work as the line wont be linear on the form `y = ax + b`. Instead we can use 4 small steps:

1. Create your fit
2. Sort your old data, or better yet generate some new data
3. Predict the model with your sorted or new data
4. Plot the prediction against the data

I assume the `visreg` package takes care of step 2-4.

Using the `gamma` model example from `help(glm)`, I'll illustrate how one can achieve this with a minimal reproducible example:

Lets start by making a model.

```
#minimum reproducible example 
#From help(glm)
clotting <- data.frame(
    u = c(5,10,15,20,30,40,60,80,100),
    lot1 = c(118,58,42,35,27,25,21,19,18))
summary(fit1 <- glm(lot1 ~ log(u), data = clotting, family = Gamma(link = "log")))
```

Now that we've fit our model, we need to actually visualize the probability. For this i want some realistic data, so i just use 100 points, evenly spaced between the minimum and maximmum value of my variable `u`

```
rn <- range(clotting$u)
newdata <- data.frame(u = seq(rn[1], rn[2], length.out = 100)) #note the data.frame
```

To get some plot-able data, I use the `predict` function.

```
plotData <- xy.coords(x = newdata$u, y = predict(fit1, newdata = newdata))
```

All that is left is to plot your data.

```
plot(plotData, ylab = "log( lot1 | u )", main = "Model plot on link scale")
```

Now we've got a plot as the one below:

[image: Model plot]

In order to add the points, one can use `points`. Note that you may have to change the `xlim` and `ylim` argument as i have done below (these set the limits on the x and y axis respectively).

```
plot(plotData, ylab = "log( lot1 | u )", main = "Model plot on link scale",
     ylim = range(clotting$lot1),
     xlim = rng)
points(clotting$u, clotting$lot1)
```

which yields the plot below:
[image]

## Bonus: Plot on original scale

If you instead wanted to plot it in the value of `lot1` (or `y` in your case) simply change

```
plotData <- xy.coords(x = newdata$u, y = predict(fit1, newdata = newdata))
```

to

```
plotData <- xy.coords(x = newdata$u, y = predict(fit1, newdata = newdata, type = "response"))
```

Comment: The graph doesn't show the points, just the model's line. Is there a way to plot the points on this graph?

Comment: Sure, i missed that point. It will be in the answer in about 15 seconds.